# assigning value to an array element's property sets all other similar elements' property

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function Block(){
    this.x = 100;
    this.y = 100;
}

// update canvas
        function UpdateCanvas(){
            // check if game is still on going
            if (!isStopped)
            {
                for(var i = segments.length - 1; i > 0 ; i--)
                {
                    segments[i] = segments[i - 1];
                }

                switch(direction)
                {
                    case "left":
                        segments[0].x = segments[0].x - pixelChange;
                        DrawCanvas();
                        break;
                    case "right":
                        segments[0].x = segments[0].x + pixelChange;
                        DrawCanvas();
                        break;
                    case "up":
                        segments[0].y = segments[0].y - pixelChange;
                        DrawCanvas();
                        break;
                    case "down":
                        segments[0].y = segments[0].y + pixelChange;
                        DrawCanvas();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

I made an array and a class called Block. Now after creating 2 objects in the array and changing blockArray[0]'s x property to a different number, blockArray[1]'s x is also changed similar to blockArray[0]'s x value instead of retaining the initial value of 100.

What was I doing wrong? and how do I change blockArray[0]'s x without affecting other objects in the array?

EDIT:
updated the code. segments is an Array with Block elements.

Comment: [Your code works just fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/hbaqp/)

Comment: yup, nothing wrong with it, are you sure you got a problem there?

Comment: still doesn't work on mine. browser is chrome btw but nothing is browser specific on my code :/

Comment: doesn't work on every browser. changing x on an element changes all the x's in every element in the array.

Comment: I get the distinct feeling you're using a `for` loop to do this.  In which case, you've got closure problems.  Exactly ***what*** your closure problems are depends on what you're doing in that for loop.

Comment: the "blockArray[0].x = blockArray[0].x + 2;" line is inside a case statement. no for loop done. updating is triggered by a setInterval.

Comment: But how are you initializing `blockArray`?  What is happening is that you are somehow getting multiple references to the same object in the array.  We could tell you how if you showed us the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed thanks. Norguard's and Mark Reed's comments led me to finding the wrong part of the code (which I forgot to include on my post).

doing:

```
for(var i = segments.length - 1; i > 0 ; i--){
    segments[i] = segments[i - 1];
}
```

saves a reference of segments[i - 1] to segments[i] instead of a saving an object. Lesson learned for me.